# Session variable lost after javascript redirect

Tags: javascript, php

I have searched high and low, but I have yet to find a solution to this specific problem.

I have a website that used by a cleaning company to allow their clients to login, view the properties that they own, and select one to input cleaning dates. Users login using a username and password that are stored in a database. The user ID is returned from the database and saved as a session variable which is then used to access information throughout the site:

```
session_start();
include 'templates/login.php';
include 'entity/loginQuery.php';
$MainEntity = new loginQuery();

if(!empty($_POST)){
    $MainEntity->setUsername($_POST["username"]);
    $MainEntity->setPassword($_POST["password"]);
    $MainEntity->processSearch();

    if($MainEntity->getUserID() != ""){
            $_SESSION["userID"] = $MainEntity->getUserID();
            header ("Location: property_selection.php");
    }

}
```

The "property selection" page uses the user ID to populate the page with that users properties. After selecting one, the user is sent to a house page where they can inpu their information. Here is where the problem occurs:

I created a button to return them to the property selection page so that they may select other properties. The button runs this javascript code:

```
function back(){

 window.location.replace('http://www.example.com/property_selection.php');
}
```

After clicking this, the user is brought to the property selection page, but $_SESSION['userID'] is now empty. Because it is empty nothing would be displayed to the screen, but the user is sent to an access denied page before any database query can take place anyways.

The strangest part is that after logging back into the website, this problem is never encountered again. Everything works perfectly. The problem can only be recreated by first closing the browser and then logging in again.

I have session_start(); at the beginning of every page and I am absolutely certain that it is redirecting to the correct URL. Ideas anyone?

PS - Sorry for the long post, but I wanted to be as specific as possible.

Comment: can't you simply do a normal link to `property_selectetion.php` without the `location.replace`? And if not: still test it, if in this case the session is there or not.

Comment: same domain? subdomain?

Comment: @Jeff I tried using a regular link but I still had the same problem. No difference. Also may be worth mentioning that typing the address manually into the address bar works fine. And no this is not a subdomain either.